# Hyundai Elantra 2001 wont start. Hear sound from the top of the engine when I turn the key on

Tags: starting, hyundai, elantra

[image]

I changed the battery and let the car sit for a long time since I was out of town. The car wont start now. I hear a clicking noise when I start the car. I opened the hood and I hear the clicking noise from the part shown in the image.

Can anyone help me here please.

Comment: Where does the end of that cable go?

Comment: @vini_i - That's the cruise control module.

Comment: @Paulster2 - Unless you are intimately familiar with that vehicle that could be two other things. It could be the break pedal position sensor and the cable could be going to the break pedal. It could also be the throttle control motor in a drive by wire system.

Comment: @vini_i - Does [this image](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTIwMFgxNjAw/z/~AoAAOxyOlhSrfV~/$_57.JPG) help you? Pulled from [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/01-02-03-04-05-06-Hyundai-Elantra-Cruise-Control-Actuator-Computer-Module-OEM/171196339379?_trksid=p2047675.c100010.m2109&_trkparms=aid%3D333008%26algo%3DRIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131231133846%26meid%3D4262dde3836b4344b8b2ac91e09f866d%26pid%3D100010%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D7%26sd%3D271611004006).

Comment: Fair enough that's the cruise control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your battery voltage? I bet if you've let it sit for a while, the battery is dead. Especially true if it's the original Hyundai battery. They are about the weakest part on the car. The part you are showing above is the cruise control module - the part which keeps you at speed (cable should be attached to the throttle somehow). If the battery is low, various parts may be making noise due to the computer really not knowing what to do with the severe low voltage.